# Binance API limit order gets filled immediately on market price

Tags: binance-api-client

I was trying to test limit order but order got filled immediately on market price. Anyone knows the probable solution to this problem? Thanks in advance

> limit_order_long = client.futures_create_order(
> symbol=symbol,
> side='BUY',
> positionSide='LONG',
> type='LIMIT',
> quantity=0.01,
> timeInForce='GTC',
> price=1680 )

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to set timeInForce='GTX', which will guarantee a maker order.

If the order request can be filled immediately, the server will reject the request.